# function results in Notice: Undefined offset: 0 on one website but not the other

Tags: php, mysql

This is bizarre. I am working on a new website using WAMP on my pc and I copy and pasted the database functions I created from another site I worked on.

Below is the function. On this new site I'm getting an error (Notice: Undefined offset: 0) whenever there is nothing that matches in the database. But, on the other site (which is hosted externally) I never get that error (never have and I just tested it specifically to make sure).

Obviously, I could just put the "return $rows[0]" in an if statement to prevent this. But, I would like to know what is causing the problem in case I need to make some changes to the old site! I'm kind of worried!

There's also another difference. On the new site I get an error when the $order is NULL, saying that $s3 is undefined. Again, I can fix it easily by just defining it along with $s1 and $s2 at the beginning. But, it works fine on my other site and has for a long time. What on earth is the difference??

```
function get_row5($table, $field, $where1, $value1, $where2=NULL, $value2=NULL, $where3=NULL, $value3=NULL, $where4=NULL, $value4=NULL, $where5=NULL, $value5=NULL, $order=NULL) {
$rows = array();
global $conn;
connect();
$s1 = "SELECT $field FROM $table WHERE $where1" . '=' . "'$value1'";
$s2 = "";
if ($where2 != NULL) {
    if ($value2 == NULL) {
        $s2 = " and $where2 is NULL";
    } else {
        $s2 = " and $where2" . ' = ' . "'$value2'";
    }
}
if ($where3 != NULL) {
    if ($value3 == NULL) {
        $s2 .= " and $where3 is NULL";
    } else {
        $s2 .= " and $where3" . ' = ' . "'$value3'";
    }
}
if ($where4 != NULL) {
    if ($value4 == NULL) {
        $s2 .= " and $where4 is NULL";
    } else {
        $s2 .= " and $where4" . ' = ' . "'$value4'";
    }
}
if ($where5 != NULL) {
    if ($value5 == NULL) {
        $s2 .= " and $where5 is NULL";
    } else {
        $s2 .= " and $where5" . ' = ' . "'$value5'";
    }
}
if ($order != NULL) {
    $s3 = " ORDER BY $order LIMIT 1";
}
$sql = $s1 . $s2 . $s3;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
$conn->close();

return $rows[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are geting this error because there is no row return from query you can overcome with following code

```
function get_row5($table, $field, $where1, $value1, $where2=NULL, $value2=NULL, $where3=NULL, $value3=NULL, $where4=NULL, $value4=NULL, $where5=NULL, $value5=NULL, $order=NULL) {
$rows = array();
global $conn;
connect();
$s1 = "SELECT $field FROM $table WHERE $where1" . '=' . "'$value1'";
$s2 = "";
$s3 = "";
if ($where2 != NULL) {
    if ($value2 == NULL) {
        $s2 = " and $where2 is NULL";
    } else {
        $s2 = " and $where2" . ' = ' . "'$value2'";
    }
}
if ($where3 != NULL) {
    if ($value3 == NULL) {
        $s2 .= " and $where3 is NULL";
    } else {
        $s2 .= " and $where3" . ' = ' . "'$value3'";
    }
}
if ($where4 != NULL) {
    if ($value4 == NULL) {
        $s2 .= " and $where4 is NULL";
    } else {
        $s2 .= " and $where4" . ' = ' . "'$value4'";
    }
}
if ($where5 != NULL) {
    if ($value5 == NULL) {
        $s2 .= " and $where5 is NULL";
    } else {
        $s2 .= " and $where5" . ' = ' . "'$value5'";
    }
}
if ($order != NULL) {
    $s3 = " ORDER BY $order LIMIT 1";
}
$sql = $s1 . $s2 . $s3;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
$conn->close();
if(count($rows))
  return $rows[0];
else
  return $rows; //<---empty row
}
```

Comment: So why is it working fine on my other site? Same exact code.

Comment: Because on other site may be your quey getting value(not emty result return)

Comment: No, because I tested it with a query that didn't get a value.